# Implement something like an extendible enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

To attain type substitutability on multiple enums in java I can have them all implement an interface. But using the object of an interface in a switch-case is challenging.

1. I cannot use the interface object directly in the switch statement. A switch statment only accepts enum, char, byte, short, int, and string.
2. I can switch on `object.getUniqueID()` where `getUniqueId` is a member of the interface, but in that case I will have to hard-code the values of the case statements. Which IMO, would be ugly and nearly impossible to refactor.

What is needed is an implementation something that

1. **Can be used in a switch-case statement, satisfying the above two issues.**
2. **Be type substitutable.**

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you insist on using it on switch statements?

Comment: I used second solution several days ago. Had base class with nested enum listing types and type field of this enum type. Works good for me.

Comment: @kocko Wouldn't if-else chain be comparatively slower? Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: What's the point of an extensible enum if you're going to use switch/case anyway? If there's a new enum value, you have to change the handling code and rebuild your system, so you might as well add the new value to the enum manually.

Comment: @mkrakhin could you maybe post a MWE?

Comment: There is no problem with the `uniqueID` thing (although I'd call it a `tag`): You simple return constants and use these constants in your `switch` statement.

Comment: @tMJ sorry, what is MWE? :)

Comment: @biziclop my use case stands in error codes. There are some common errors, and then there are some specific errors. Do not want to write the common errors again and again with each specific enum. Plus, would want to do a switch case on the error code received(Common or specific).

Comment: @mkrakhin, Minimum Working Example.

Comment: @mkrakhin Min. working example

Comment: @tMJ Oh, I see, so you want one enum to "inherit" the values of another. That's a different problem to what I had in mind. I would use an interface that declares `getUniqueId()` and provides a static implementation that creates the unique id from the actual type name and the enum value. I'll try to post an example later.

Comment: @Clashsoft the constants can be replaced by a single enum containing all the values. Altleast in the mess is equivalent. In the single enum containing all the values, it would be easier to refactor.

Comment: @biziclop what would then go in the case statement is hard-coded values of the possible return values of the `getUniqueId` function. Which IMO, also said earlier, is messy.

Comment: Personally, I would use `int` constants because of the overhead of `enum` and switching on it. But that's just personal preference, an enum works as well and avoids 'unknown' IDs.

Comment: @tMJ No, what would go there is `Interface.getUniqueIdFor( MyEnum.FOO )`,.

Comment: @tMJ smth like this http://pastebin.com/85yUn1pQ

Comment: @biziclop, wouldn't the case statement require a constant expression ?

Comment: @tMJ Ah yeah, forgot about that. Don't use switch/case then :)

Comment: @mkrakhin Wouldn't extending the Base class require the subclass's `type`to be in the enum of the base class? How is it better than having a single enum, because in essence it is a single enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use a single enum which has all the possible `enum` values or you need to check the type before you switch.

```
MyInterface value = ...

if (value instanceof EnymType1) {
    switch((EnumType1) value) {
        case ...

    }
} else if (value instanceof EnumType2) {
    switch((EnumType2) value) {
        case ...

    }
}
```

Instead of using a switch you can have a `Map<MyInterface, Consumer<MyInterface>>` as this is extensible dynamically but has close to the same performance of a switch.

Comment: Well, if tMJ has a lot of descdendants this part could be a bottle-neck. `instanceof` works really slow.

Comment: @mkrakhin That's news to me, have you got any benchmarks that prove it?

Comment: @biziclop well, no :( But as far as I remember, every invokation of instanceof will ascend through whole type ierarchy of `EnumType`. Suppose it's slower than switch.

Comment: @mkrakhin https://github.com/OpenHFT/jvm-micro-benchmarks/blob/master/src/main/java/javatest/InstanceOfMain.java instanecof can take 2.2 ns

Comment: @PeterLawrey don't have time to build my jmh project. Could you compare to switch/case? Just interesting.

Comment: @PeterLawrey This solution would likely work for my case, yet I think "inheritance" in enums would not hurt. `Oracle are you listening?` 

Gonna keep the thread open for a couple of days for any other interesting solution.

Comment: @tMJ I doubt Oracle could change it ;) Historically enums implicilty extend Enum class.

Comment: @mkrakhin yes they do, but there must be some way possible, at least for Oracle, to provide the functionality. *Keeping fingers crossed*

Comment: @tMJ You can generate a single `enum` from multiple `enum` and use this instead. The problem is that this combination must be available at compile time to use a `switch`